# How to compile the source code based on the platform in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have implemented a plugin in Flutter. And it is running good with android and ios. Later added web platform support. It also working good in web version. After adding web platform support, I tried to execute the mobile version android from android studio.

Code is not compiling and giving the below error messages.

```
/lib/native_video_view_web.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

I understood this is due to 'dart:html' package, which is ONLY available for web and NOT for the mobile version. Here is some discussion about the same [Reference Link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56829). Nobody mentioned how to compile the code based on the platform to avoid this issue.

Later I have observed, [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) flutter plugin source code. They are also supporting web version. And noticed that they are also using 'dart:html' in their web implementation. And i tried to execute mobile and web build. All are working fine with any problem. I am not understanding how they have managed to compiled code based on the platform. So 'dart:html' will not create problem for mobile builds.

Does anybody have any idea, how to deal with this issue.

Comment: Follow the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#conditionally-importing-and-exporting-library-files).

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to understand how to utilize for differentiation of platforms. Would be great, if you suggest any example for this.

Comment: can any one can help me with example?